# How to keep images from blinking on first hover

Tags: html, css, flicker, preloading

I am not great with javascript and I don't know how to do "preloading" of images which is what I THINK I have to do here?

If you visit this website, the first time you hover over the images, they BLINK white. But from that point on they are fine and all looks good. This is annoying at first and I'd like to avoid it. I've moved the JS that I do have into the footer but other than that I am not sure what to do to fix it. Suggestions? [Here is the website.](http://colormycollege.com/)

**Here is the css code:**

```
.primaryContainer {
  height: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  min-width: 0;
  max-width: none;
}
#partycontainerforbgimages {
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-top: -45px;
  clear: none;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 0;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  min-height: 0;
}
#paintpartyimgcontainer {
  float: none;
  height: 650px;
  clear: none;
  width: 59.99976%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 40.265253%;
  z-index: 0;
  display: block;
  min-height: 0;
  background-image: url(img/glowparty_hover.png);
  background-attachment: scroll;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat;
  -webkit-transition: all .15s linear;
  transition: all .15s linear;
}
#_5kimgcontainer {
  float: left;
  height: 650px;
  clear: none;
  width: 60%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 8;
  border-right-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.952941);
  border-right-width: 14px;
  border-right-style: solid;
  display: block;
  min-height: 0;
  background-image: url(img/5kimg_hover.jpg);
  background-attachment: scroll;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  min-width: 0;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0%, 75% 100%, 0% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0%, 75% 100%, 0% 100%);
  -webkit-transition: all .15s linear;
  transition: all .15s linear;
}
#_5kimgcontainer:hover {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  background-image: url(img/5kimg.jpg);
  background-attachment: scroll;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat;
}
#paintpartyimgcontainer:hover {
  background-image: url(img/glowparty.png);
  background-attachment: scroll;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat;
}
#_5k_container {
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  clear: none;
  width: 50%;
  min-width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  min-height: 0;
}
#paintparty_container {
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  clear: none;
  width: 50%;
  min-width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  display: block;
  min-height: 0;
}
#_5k {
  float: left;
  width: 242.5px;
  max-width: 252.5px;
  height: 253px;
  margin-left: 25.227476%;
  margin-top: -165.75px;
  clear: none;
  color: #000;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-width: 242.5px;
  min-height: 253px;
  padding-right: 0;
  margin-right: 30px;
  max-height: 253px;
  -webkit-transition: all .15s linear;
  transition: all .15s linear;
}
#paintparty {
  float: left;
  width: 220.515625px;
  max-width: 316.11px;
  height: 217px;
  margin-left: 40.928819%;
  margin-top: 232px;
  clear: none;
  color: #000;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-width: 220.52px;
  min-height: 217px;
  max-height: 310px;
  -webkit-transition: all .15s linear;
  transition: all .15s linear;
}
#pickyourpartybox {
  float: none;
  height: 117px;
  clear: none;
  width: 180px;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 16;
  border: 5px solid #efeeee;
  border-top-left-radius: 17px;
  border-top-right-radius: 17px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 17px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 17px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.309804) 0 0 7px 3px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.309804) 0 0 7px 3px;
  margin-top: 258px;
  margin-left: 87.653061%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.560784);
  margin-right: 30px;
}
#logo_overlay_grouping {
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  clear: none;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 26;
  display: block;
  min-height: 0;
  overflow: visible;
  margin-top: -45px;
  margin-left: 0;
}
#pickyourpartytext {
  float: none;
  font-size: 2em;
  width: 62.115127%;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1em;
  margin: 23px auto 0;
  clear: none;
  min-height: 78px;
  font-family: helvetica;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #efeeee;
}
#header {
  float: none;
  height: 45px;
  clear: none;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 0;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.843137);
  border-bottom-width: 6px;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  display: block;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.843137);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.843137) 0 3px 3px 0;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.843137) 0 3px 3px 0;
}
#headernav {
  float: none;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  clear: none;
  width: 545px;
  padding: 15px 0;
  position: static;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
#facebooklink {
  float: left;
  font-size: 1em;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: .3em;
  margin-left: .00390625%;
  margin-top: 0;
  clear: none;
  min-height: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  color: #ec89ee;
  font-family: helvetica;
  display: block;
  -webkit-transition: all .15s linear;
  transition: all .15s linear;
}
#twitterlink {
  float: left;
  font-size: 1em;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: .3em;
  margin-left: 24.009454%;
  margin-top: 0;
  clear: none;
  min-height: 0;
  display: block;
  margin-right: 0;
  color: #4bd3ef;
  font-family: helvetica;
  -webkit-transition: all .15s linear;
  transition: all .15s linear;
}
#instagramlink {
  float: left;
  font-size: 1em;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: .3em;
  margin-left: 24.009454%;
  margin-top: 0;
  clear: none;
  min-height: 0;
  display: block;
  margin-right: 0;
  color: #7fee81;
  font-family: helvetica;
  -webkit-transition: all .15s linear;
  transition: all .15s linear;
}
#footer {
  float: left;
  height: 45px;
  clear: none;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.843137);
  -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.843137) 0 -3px 3px 0;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.843137) 0 -3px 3px 0;
  position: fixed;
  top: 94%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 15;
  overflow: scroll;
  right: auto;
  bottom: auto;
}
#footer_text {
  float: none;
  font-size: .5em;
  width: 38.45%;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: .5em;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-top: 0;
  clear: none;
  min-height: 100%;
  font-family: helvetica;
  color: #efeeee;
  padding-top: 11px;
  margin-right: auto;
}
#textspan {
  float: none;
  font-size: .6em;
  line-height: 1em;
  font-weight: 300;
}
#_5k:hover {
  width: 252.5px;
  min-width: 0;
  display: block;
  min-height: 263px;
  height: 263px;
  max-width: 252.5px;
  max-height: 263px;
}
#paintparty:hover {
  width: 224.515625px;
  min-width: 224.52px;
  display: block;
  height: 221px;
  min-height: 221px;
  max-width: 224.52px;
  max-height: 221px;
}
#textspan1 {
  float: none;
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 1em;
}
#facebooklink:hover {
  color: rgba(236, 137, 238, 0.74902);
}
#twitterlink:hover {
  color: rgba(75, 211, 239, 0.74902);
}
#instagramlink:hover {
  color: rgba(127, 238, 129, 0.74902);
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 750px) {
  #_5kimgcontainer {
    width: 100%;
    position: static;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: none;
  }
  #paintpartyimgcontainer {
    width: 100%;
    position: static;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-left: 40.264583%;
    clear: none;
    display: none;
  }
  #pickyourpartybox {
    display: none;
  }
  #_5k_container {
    width: 100%;
    position: static;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin-top: -7px;
    margin-left: auto;
    clear: none;
    margin-right: auto;
    float: none;
    height: 107.54818%;
    background-image: url(img/5kimg_hover.jpg);
    background-attachment: scroll;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: repeat repeat;
    border-bottom: 10px solid #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 10px 5px -8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 10px 5px -8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    box-shadow: 0 10px 5px 17px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  }
  #paintparty_container {
    width: 100%;
    position: static;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    clear: none;
    margin-right: auto;
    float: none;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url(img/glowparty_hover.png);
    background-attachment: scroll;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 4px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 4px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    box-shadow: inset 0 4px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  }
  #_5k {
    margin: 100px auto 57px;
    float: none;
    clear: none;
  }
  #paintparty {
    margin: 100px auto 57px;
    float: none;
    clear: none;
  }
  #pickyourpartytext {
    width: 0;
  }
  #logo_overlay_grouping {
    position: static;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }
  #_5k_container:hover {
    background-image: url(img/5kimg.jpg);
    background-attachment: scroll;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat;
  }
  #footer {
    width: 100%;
    clear: both;
    bottom: auto;
    top: 96.3%;
  }
  #partycontainerforbgimages {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
  #footer_text {
    margin-top: 0;
    clear: none;
    line-height: 1em;
    width: 77.45%;
    font-size: .4em;
  }
  #paintparty_container:hover {
    background-image: url(img/glowparty.png);
    background-attachment: scroll;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat;
  }
  #textspan1 {
    line-height: 1em;
    font-size: 1em;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 650px) {
  #twitterlink {
    margin-left: 15%;
  }
  #instagramlink {
    margin-left: 15%;
  }
  #headernav {
    width: 400px;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 433px) {
  #twitterlink {
    margin-left: 15%;
  }
  #instagramlink {
    margin-left: 15%;
  }
  #headernav {
    width: 272px;
  }
}
```

**And here is the HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="boilerplate.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="page.css">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale = 1.0,maximum-scale = 1.0">
</head>
<body>

<div id="primaryContainer" class="primaryContainer clearfix">
    <div id="header" class="clearfix">
        <div id="headernav" class="clearfix">
            <a id="facebooklink" href="https://www.facebook.com/colormycollege5K" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square" aria-hidden="true"></i> Facebook</a>
            <a id="twitterlink" href="https://twitter.com/colormycollege" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter-square" aria-hidden="true"></i> Twitter</a>
            <a id="instagramlink" href="https://www.instagram.com/colormycollege/" target="_blank"> <i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i> Instagram</a>
  </div>
    </div>
    <div id="logo_overlay_grouping" class="clearfix">
        <div id="_5k_container" class="clearfix">
            <div id="pickyourpartybox" class="clearfix">
                <p id="pickyourpartytext">
                <span id="textspan">PICK YOUR</span><br />PARTY
                </p>
            </div>
            <a href="http://www.5k.colormycollege.com/">
                <img id="_5k" src="img/logo_5k.png" class="image" />
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="paintparty_container" class="clearfix">
            <a href="#">
                <img id="paintparty" src="img/Logo_paint.png" class="image" />
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="partycontainerforbgimages" class="clearfix">
        <div id="_5kimgcontainer" class="clearfix">
        </div>
        <div id="paintpartyimgcontainer" class="clearfix">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
<footer>
<div id="footer" class="clearfix">
        <p id="footer_text">
        &copy; Copyright 2016. All Rights Reserved.  &#x7c; Design By&#x3a; <a id="textspan1" href="#" target="_blank">Cyndee Adkins Design&nbsp;</a><br />
        </p>
    </div>
        <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/0847995977.js"></script>
    </footer>
 </html>
```

Comment: Yes, preloading is what you want to do to avoid the flash. [There are plenty of solutions around that can show you how to preload images with JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+preload+image).

Comment: I will see if I can figure out how to add a JavaScripty preload. I don't think straight css will work because I tried adding some and it didnt work.  This code just broke the design. #_5kimgcontainer:before
  {content: url("img/5kimg_hover.jpg");
   width:0;
   height:0;
   visibility:hidden;}
   
#paintpartyimgcontainer:before
  {content: url("img/glowparty_hover.png");
   width:0;
   height:0;
   visibility:hidden;}